# MinGW-GCC without libstd++ but with exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, mingw, libstdc++

(I am normally using C not C++ so please excuse this question:)

I am trying to use MinGW-GCC C++11 without libstdc++ (called freestanding) to avoid falling under its GPL.

I had some trouble to get it to work, but this *almost* does what i want:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -s -Os -lkernel32 -luser32 
  -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror 
  -Wl,-e_Main -mwindows
  -nostdlib -ffreestanding -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions
```

The last problem now is, that i would like exceptions, so if i remove `-fno-exceptions` again i get

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x265): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
main.cpp:(.eh_frame+0xcb): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
bad reloc address 0xcb in section `.eh_frame'
```

I found that these helper-functions are needed to unwind the stack and call the destructors on that path. (I find it a little crazy that these are considered part of the Standard Library. If gcc cannot provide the core language without them they should be intrinsic.)

I have looked at e.g. STLport and Apache stdcxx but neither are C++11, also I only need exceptions!

**Is there a way to provide just the necessary helper functions so exceptions work?**

Comment: I think that you can use libstdc++ whithout falling under GPL. See this [link](http://lwn.net/Articles/549573/)

Comment: @memo1288 the exemption-clause does not apply in my case. i can provide more info if you want - but i rather get this working